# need to modify my sort pipe so that it is a passthrough (like cat)

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a script that as a pipe step  |sort $sortstring| .  The sortstring contains different types of sort depending upon arguments to the script.  I recently added nosort as an argument and my sortstring is -m (meaning merge and do not sort).  This seems to work, however it is inefficient.   I do not want to write a test around this code such as if [[ $arg == "nosort" ]]; then do steps w/out sort pipe injected; else do steps w sort pipe injected as the steps are very complicated (a large awk script proceeds it).  I could make the "sort $sortstring" into a shell variable and set this shell variable to "cat" in the nosort case.  However, this is very complicated.  I guess good programming would suggest fictionalizing the script (place the proceeding complicated command in a function).  Can someone suggest an efficient alternative to allow nosort?

Comment: A (well-formated) short code example could be helpful for clarification

Comment: if [[ $1 == "sort5" ]]; then sortstring="-T -k5,5";fi;  if [[ $1 == "sort3" ]];then sortstring="-T -k3,3";fi; if [[ $1 == "nosort" ]]; then sortstring="-m";fi;  cat ./input | sort $sortstring > ./outfile

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your input through an `if` statement, which is a command like any other.

```
... | if [[ $arg == nosort ]]; then cat; else sort ...; fi | ...
```

The commands following `then`, `elif`, or `else` inherit their file descriptors from the `if` statement.

Comment: Shorter: … | ([ x$arg = xnosort ] || sort …) | …

Comment: True, although I'd use `... | [ "$arg" = nosort] || sort | ...` instead. (The `x` hack isn't necessary in a POSIX-conformant shell.)

Comment: Yes, it isn't. But it's important to remember the quotation marks in this case

Comment: You need the quotation marks regardless; `x$arg` can expand to multiple words if `$arg` contains `IFS` characters or glob metacharacters.

Comment: (([[ "$outputsorttype" == "nosort" ]] && cat ) || sort ...) is what I think you meant.  w/o the cat it does not seem to work

Comment: Right; `[` gets  the standard input (and ignores it), but doesn't pass it on to standard output. Honestly, I'd stick with the explicit `if` statement, though; `a && b || c` is not, in general, equivalent to `if a; then b; else c; fi`.